# A button in excel sheet does not work for the first time

Tags: excel, vba

I write the below code for a button which have put that button in a excel sheet. And I have a form (userform1). When I click on the button for the first time the listbox2 and textbox16 does not change, but for the second time, they change. Does my code have any problem? (I added "load userform1" or some another codes but again that does not work for the first time)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 2 

UserForm1.Show

UserForm1.ListBox2.Selected(1) = True 

UserForm1.TextBox16.Value = 84

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the moment you issue the `Show`, the form is displayed *modal*, which means it has the focus and you cannot switch back to Excel (or any other open form).
As a consequence, also the Sub is interrupted.

It continues to run when the form is closed or hidden. So setting the values for the listbox and the texbox is done only after you showed the form (and the user closed it again). When you now execute the code a 2nd time, it looks as if the fields where set successfully this time - but that's not true, they got the values from the first call. You can prove that by setting different values for every call.

Solution: Move the `Show` command at the end of your sub, after you have set all form fields.

An alternative is to show the form *non-modal*: `UserForm1.Show False`. In that case the Sub will be executed completely, even if the form is already displayed. Showing the form non-modal will enable the user to switch back and forth between Excel and the Form, which might be handy, but you need to think carefully what should happen when the user presses the button on the sheet again.